# Membership table in l2s schema

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-membership

I often find myself in need for some user data like Username,Profile properties along with some other data from other tables in my database where Tables are in relation through UserId(guid).Let me explain:

```
aspnet_Users table:
UserId
username
...

Some table from which I retrive data:
Id
Post
DateTime
UserId
...
```

So for each post I pull (usually over 20 at time) I need username for each one of them. It seems like expensive deal to call something like:

```
  string username = Membership.GetUser(UserID).UserName;
```

for each item. Seems like I am making 20 additional calls to database. What is proper way to do this? Should I Include aspnet_Users table in my Linq to Sql scheme and then join so I can pull it at one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to. There are at least two possible approaches.

First, you can have a custom membership provider which uses your own database and custom tables from the database. This way you don't deal with two databases and don't have to perform additional calls.

Second, if you stil want to stick with the builtin `SqlMembershipProvider` which uses `aspnetdb` database and thus you have two databases - the user database and your application database, you can create a linked server/synonym from your application database to the `aspnetdb` database. There's a small issue with `sqlmetal.exe` which prevents it from generating the linq2sql model of linked tables but you can create models for both databases and then just put then in the same namespace:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2008/06/linq-and-synonyms-linked-servers.html

This way you'll have a linq2sql model of the database **with** linked tables which will allow you to create joins across databases. In your scenario it means a single linq2sql statement to retrieve posts with user names.

Comment: this does not address the question. First of all, there is no need to have TWO databases with the builtin provider, you can add the tables to your own database. Second of all, if you use linked tables you still need to add them to the DBML and you still have the choice between joining them or using Membership.GetUser()..

Comment: This DOES answer the question. I haven't said that you HAVE to have two databases. What I wrote is that EVEN IF you have two databases, you can link them using linked servers / synonyms. Then, if you have the complete schema in the linq2sql model, you can read the data using a single query. The question was about 20 additional queries which you can easily avoid with this approach. Although your opinion on this answer differs from the opinion of the user who asked the question and accepted this as his answer, I still respect your right to downvote me. I am not going to do the same, regards :)

Comment: Reversed downvote (had to edit to do so, but only added a space).

Comment: Thanks, your approach is also of course correct, I've upvoted you too.

Comment: Still I believe the fundamentel question is: do I add the internals of the membershipprovider to my DBML and accept that I am disrespecting the encapsulation or not...

Answer (score 2):

> > Should I Include aspnet_Users table in my Linq to Sql scheme and then join so I can pull it at one time?

Yes, at least thats the way I do it.

Another option would be to create a dictionary and store all your users there and do the lookup in memory but in that case you need to monitor changes to your users so the join seems a much easier solution.